# Update remote tables using linked server

Tags: sql-server-2000, linked-server

I wanna update remote table with following code but I encounter this error:

```
`Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Invalid object name 'f1'.`
```

code:

```
declare @temp table
    (
      co_kargah bigint,
      code_ostan nvarchar(10)
    )
    insert into @temp 
          select co_kargah,code_ostan
                from Tbl_ghireHadese_Temp
                where InsUpKey=2

                update  f1  /* Error location*/
                set

                f1.modate_mogharar=tbl_ghireHadese.modate_mogharar,
                f1.t_pm_mogharar=tbl_ghireHadese.t_pm_mogharar

    from openquery([lnkworkersystem],'select * from Bazresi_Kar.dbo.Tbl_ghireHadese') f1
                inner join @temp temp
                 on temp.co_kargah=f1.co_kargah
                   and temp.code_ostan=f1.code_ostan
                   and temp.t_bazresiFE=f1.t_bazresiFE
                inner join tbl_ghireHadese
                     on temp.co_kargah=tbl_ghireHadese.co_kargah
                        and temp.code_ostan=tbl_ghireHadese.code_ostan
                        and temp.t_bazresiFE=tbl_ghireHadese.t_bazresiFE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the SET clause. You can't specify aliases in the column assign. There is no need because you've already told SQL Server what table in the UPDATE clause

Should be:

```
update  f1 
set
   modate_mogharar = tbl_ghireHadese.modate_mogharar,
   t_pm_mogharar = tbl_ghireHadese.t_pm_mogharar
from 
....
```

Note: SQL Server doesn't always give the correct line number for errors

Edit: use 4 part object names as normal tables

```
...

FROM
    lnkworkersystem.Bazresi_Kar.dbo.Tbl_ghireHadese
    inner join
    @temp temp on temp.co_kargah=f1.co_kargah
    ...
```

Also, your temp table has 3 columns in the JOIN but is only defined with 2. `t_bazresiFE` is missing. So it will error again...

Comment: I wanna use OpenQuery but in your sample code you didn't use OpenQuery.Please give an example with openQuery